# Desactivar rotación de pantalla en android

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación para android y no quiero que a la pantalla se le aplique la rotación de la misma.

¿Cómo hago para desactivar la opción de rotación de pantalla en [android](/questions/tagged/android) para cuando se gire el teléfono este se quede en vertical?

Comment: ¿Es una pregunta de programación o de uso?. Pareciera que lo anterior es una pregunta ociosa pero dado muchos internautas que podrían pasar por aquí no están familiarizados con SOes es conveniente que la pregunta sea clara al respecto.

Comment: Es una pregunta de programación ya que recién estoy iniciando en android y la pregunta creo es clara y directo a la duda, no sabría que otros términos usar.

Comment: Lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo con la propiedad **[`screenOrientation`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen)** dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name=".miActivity"
...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Otra opción, la cual implica agregar código por cada actividad, es:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Se agrega inmediatamente después de `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...
...
...
```

**Actualmente no existe forma para deshabilitar la rotación para toda la aplicación.** Como solución "global" podrias extender todas tus Actividades de una "Actividad Padre" que tenga definido:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Comment: puse lo que comentas pero hay un detalle y es que tengo que ponerle a cada actividad la opcion android:screenOrientation="portrait" para que no gire, hay alguna manera de hacerlo global.

Comment: este método es para definir por actividad desde el Manifest.xml, es el método más común, si lo deseas programaticamente también tendrías que agregar código por cada actividad. Lo agrego a mi respuesta.

Comment: Pues si es la opción mas accesible, gracias.

Comment: Esta respuesta esta obsoleta en versiones recientes @Jorgesys

Answer (score 2):

En el archivo **AndroidManifest.xml** dentro del bloque **Activity** con la propiedad `screenOrientation` puedes limitar la rotación de la pantalla en tu caso seria poner su valor en `portrait` para bloquear la vista verticalmente, pero puedes juntar más valores con el separador |, lista de valores:

- `unspecified`
- `behind`
- `landscape`
- `portrait`
- `reverseLandscape`
- `reversePortrait`
- `sensorLandscape`
- `sensorPortrait`
- `userLandscape`
- `userPortrait`
- `sensor`
- `fullSensor`
- `nosensor`
- `user`
- `fullUser`
- `locked`

Puedes leer más sobre ellos en la [Documentación oficial de Android](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

Comment: En tu respuesta le das todos los valores posibles, pero no le indicas cual usar, ni que hacen los demás. Por favor mejórala un poco.

Comment: Modifico la respuesta para que quede más claro el valor que debe poner para bloquear la vista verticalmente.

Answer (score 2):

Estaba leyendo de que es algo tedioso tener que escribir este código en cada actividad y es válido, esta es una buena alternativa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al igual que esta clase "ClasePadre" extiende de AppCompatActivity.. podrías extender tus actividades de ClasePadre así evitarías tanto código
y hacer los cambios según tus requerimientos
Saludos = )
bueno aquí está el código

```
public class ClasePadre extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: listo ! @Mariano

Comment: @Mariano bueno lo que estoy haciendo es crear una clase que extiende AppCompatActivity; como todas las actividades extienden de ella.. así sólo extendería de ClasePadre.. para heredar todos los cambios de forma digamos que global; y esto sirven también para otras cosas como inyectar con Butterknife(tener que inyectar en todas las actividades con ButterKnife.bind(this);), usar Realm(Para configurar) o un buen ejemplo denegar orientaciones de pantalla y estirar la pantalla y no mostrar las opciones de hora, batería, wifi.. =)

Answer (score 1):

Lo siento pero no existe forma de hacerlo global. La propiedad "`screenOrientation`" se debe usar en cada '`activity`', a nivel de '`application`' no existe nada parecido.