# actividad Splash Screen solo vertical, actividad login inicie en vertical por default

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

[image: Actividad 1 Splash]
[image: Actividad 2 login (Home)]
Tengo dos actividades:

1. Es mi splash screen
2. Es mi login

Necesito que mi splash screen (actividad 1), solo maneje la posición vertical, dura 5 segundos mi splash screen. Inmediatamente después inicia el login (actividad 2) pero necesito que aunque el teléfono este en posición horizontal el login (actividad 2) comience en la posición vertical por default (ya me hicieron esa observación los usuarios y se ve mal el login, ademas de que no debe ser permitido en los teléfonos).

No puedo bloquear la posición horizontal en esta actividad porque tengo código que permite el uso de la tablet tanto en posición vertical como horizontal, probé esto, pero estoy seguro que solo estoy permitiendo la orientación vertical tanto en el teléfono como en la tablet y por ahora no cuento con una tablet a la mano para verificar mi teoría, ¿que podría hacer?.

Comment: Debes de mostrar el código que tengas hasta el momento, de esa forma los usuarios pueden ver y opinar sugerencias de como hacerlo.

Comment: Para mi opinion deberías rediseñar los layouts que se vean bien tanto en vertical y horizontal, las apps que se fijan sola en una tableta "si tienes teclado" es horroroso estar girando la cabeza

Comment: @JuanLopez esta pregunta aplica para Xamarin también, y se respondió aquí http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297/desactivar-rotaci%C3%B3n-de-pantalla-en-android saludos!

Comment: Para una mejor lectura pon el código en formato código

Answer (score 1):

Esta pregunta se puede decir que ya fue anteriormente respondida ya que aplica para `Xamarin` también:

**[Desactivar rotación de pantalla en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297/desactivar-rotaci%C3%B3n-de-pantalla-en-android)**

Puedes realizarlo con la propiedad `screenOrientation` dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Con esto aseguras que tu pantalla Splash siempre inicie en orientación vertical.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes añadir `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` en tu archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".MiActividad"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Con esto harás que tu actividad solo se mantenga de manera horizontal siempre, ahora bien si no lo quieres poner en el archivo `AndroidManifest.xml` puedes usar:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Así podrás fijar tu actividad siempre de manera horizontal, lo pudieras usar conjunto a una validación para saber si es una tablet o un smartphone sacando el tamaño de la pantalla de esta manera:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int ancho = metrics.widthPixels;
int alto = metrics.heightPixels;
float xdpi = metrics.xdpi;
float ydpi = metrics.ydpi;
```

Ya sería cuestión que lo valides a tus necesidades.

Comment: Lo tengo en Xamarin Android amigo, lo acabo de editar con las imagenes de cada actividad ( 2), gracias por tu tiempo y espero me puedas ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Puedes revisar aquí: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861289/lock-screen-orientation-to-portrait-when-scanning-with-zxing-library-xamarin-an

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo solo debes poner esta linea de codigo dentro de la etiqueta  en tu archivo androidManifiest.xml 
android:screenOrientation="portrait">

Por lo cual tu Manifiest quedaria parecido a este

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivyty"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Lo tengo en Xamarin Android Amigo, subi una foto arriba. Saludos y gracias por tomarte algo de tu tiempo y contestar ojala me puedas ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te sugeriría dos cosas:

Pon sólo el atributo de screen orientation en la splash, porque es la que debe ir siempre fija.

```
[Activity(Label = "Ejemplo-Splash", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Y en la segunda, directamente no uses ninguna orientación

```
[Activity(Label = "Ejemplo-MiVista")]
```

Utiliza el método `SetRequestedOrientation()` en el `OnCreate()` para poner la orientación que necesites por defecto. Luego, cuando te sea necesario, puedes volver a utilizar el método para poner la orientación como prefieras.

Para iniciar los valores dependiendo del dispositivo, échale un vistaso a  [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627774/android-allow-portrait-and-landscape-for-tablets-but-force-portrait-on-phone) enlace. La idea es tener una condición booleana que te indique qué orientación asignar utilizando recursos de valores.

**P.D:** Si no tienes un dispositivo a mano, siempre puedes utilziar [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/); a mi siempre me ha ido mejor que cualquier otro emulador, tienes imágenes de teléfonos y tablets, y puedes emular el cambio de orientación ;)