# Como puedo validar la rotación de mi aplicación

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buen día colegas, lo que pasa es que tengo un problema en mi Activity ya que cuando rotamos la pantalla (Giramos) en Lasdscape, en mi Activity parece que todo lo que tengo en onCreate se reinicia, tengo unos request en onCreate y  cuando giro, me vuelve a hacer los request. Alguien sabe que pasa y como se puede solucionar???? Gracias.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tomar_fotos_de_solicitud);
    frameImagesLoad = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameImagesLoad);
    btFab = (FabSpeedDial) findViewById(R.id.btFab);
    myDialog = new Dialog(this);
    bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Home.this);
    tvTiempo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTiempo);

    requestParaConsumirWebService(parametro1);
    requestParaConsumirWebService2(parametro2);
    requestParaConsumirWebService3(parametro3);
}
```

Comment: Hola, puedes definir una rotaciòn evitando se vuelva a construir la Activity, esto se realiza dentro del AndroidManifest.xml, agregue respuesta,saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El comportamiento que tienes en tu aplicación es **normal**. Bajo la filosofía que android maneja. cuando realizar una rotación y **no se controla esa rotación** lo que hace el activity es reiniciarse, es decir recrea todo de nuevo. Por más que los valores/atributos que tienes en tu activity ya tiene valor.

Referencia ->https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

> - **No falle ni pierda el progreso del usuario** cuando se gire la pantalla entre la orientación horizontal y la vertical..

**Pero** eso no significa que no se pueda controlar este comportamiento.

En el pasado se utilizaba los métodos `onSaveInstanceState` y `onRestoreInstanceState`

Basicamente en el método `onSaveInstanceState` se utilizaba para guardar información, por ejemplo strings, enteros, parcelables, etc. Con una respectiva llave. Luego cuando el device rota todo se destruye pero como tu información fue guardad, con el método `onRestoreInstanceState` obteníamos la información que fue previamente guardada en el método `onSaveInstanceState`. Para realizar esto se utilizaba la llave que se utilizó previamente.

Referencia y ejemplos -> https://experto.dev/android-guardar-estado-activity/

Si bien era una buena manera de controlar este escenario. Hace un tiempo Android lanzó su stack de librerías Jetpack. Son muchas las características que tiene, te dejo la referencia por si te interesa revisarlo [Jetpack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/?gclid=CjwKCAjw57b3BRBlEiwA1ImytkKUpvSMWN1KVJBFwUIYjOJPZfHI-9PP54tL9L3KMEKHE-za7eaeQhoCl1kQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

En una de sus carácteristicas es manejar esta perdida de información que se origina cuando hace se rota el device. Pero ya no utiliza los métodos previamente mencionados. Reemplaza esto que una patron llamado MVVM, que básicamente es guardar esos valores en una clase aparte y por mas que tu device rote, como estos parámetros fueron guardados en una clase aparte, la información no se pierde. Dentro de todo esto tenemos al ViewModel y Livedata, que son las dos clases que se encargan de hacer este proceso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en la imagen anterior utilizando viewModel y LiveData se evita todo este problema. Te dejo una referencia de como implementar ViewModel y Livedata para tus proyectos [Link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=es).

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo verificare mas tarde muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al girar el dipositivo la Activity se destruye y se vuelve a crear, por esta razòn se vuelve a llamar nuevamente `onCreate()`.

Si no deseas suceda esto una opciòn es bloquear la rotaciòn de tu `Activity`, definiendo solo soporte la orientaciòn `portrait` o `landscape`, lo debes realizar dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, ejemplo:

```
<activity android:name=".miActivity"
    ...
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Revisa esta pregunta:

[Desactivar rotación de pantalla en android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297/desactivar-rotaci%C3%B3n-de-pantalla-en-android/1720#1720)